# Handlebars: Pass helper generated value to partial

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I created a Handlebars helper for our own i18n library which looks a bit like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', (type, key, optionalValue) => optionalValue ?
  i18n[type](key, optionalValue.hash) :
  i18n[type](key)
);
```

I want to use this helper te generate a value to pass on to a partial. Something like this:

```
{{> myPartial header={{i18n 'text' 'my.translation.key}}}}
```

As expected this generated a syntax error.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nest helper you can use `(`

```
{{myPartial header=(i18n 'text' 'my.translation.key')}}
```